# Result for statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Been looking for a proof of $\frac{(b- \beta)^TX^TX(b-\beta)}{\sigma^2} \sim X_p^2$ for days. THis is for the regression model $y = X\beta + \epsilon$ ,$\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2I)$ where b is the least square estimator. I thought about starting from $\frac{(b_i - \beta_i)}{\sqrt{\sigma((X^TX)^{-1})_{ii}}} \sim N(0,1). $ but can't simplify to the desired answer. Any useful hints will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First absorb the $\sigma^2$ into the $\epsilon$ factors in the statistic so that we can get rid of it and take the components of $\epsilon$ to be $N(0,1).$

We have $$ b = \beta + (X'X)^{-1}X' \epsilon$$ so your quantity becomes $$ \epsilon'X (X'X)^{-1}(X'X )(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon = \epsilon'X(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon.$$

The matrix $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is symmetric so it can be diagonalized by an orthogonal transformation. Also a little more work reveals that it is actually a projection operator onto the column space of $X$ (think about what it does to vectors perpendicular to all the columns of $X$ and then what it does  to $X)$. It follows that since $X$ has $p$ columns, when diagonalized, $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ has $p$ one's and $n-p$ zeros on the diagonal.

(We do not have to worry about whether $X$'s column space has dimension $p.$ The fact that we've written $(X'X)^{-1}$ implies that we are assuming $X$ to be full column rank, a standard regression assumption.)

Let $O$ be an orthogonal matrix diagonalizing $X(X'X)^{-1}X'.$ Then we can write the statistic as $$ (O\epsilon)'O(X(X'X)^{-1}X')O'(O\epsilon) = \eta' D\eta$$ where $D$ is diagonal $p$ ones and $n-p$ zeros on its diagonal and $\eta = O\epsilon$. Now we can use the fact that since $O$ is orthogonal, $\eta$'s components are also iid $N(0,1)'s.$ So if we chose the diagonalization that puts all the ones first, the statistic can be written $$\eta_1^2+\eta_2^2+\ldots \eta_p^2 $$ which is $\chi^2_p.$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. I partially understand your solution but need some clarification with some. Sorry Im not that great in linear algebra.

Comment: 1) why is this true? 't follows that since XX has pp columns, when diagonalized, $X(X′X)^{−1}X′$ has p one's and n−p zeros on the diagonal.'

Comment: @bstead A projection matrix $P$ has the property $P^2=P.$ It follows that it's eigenvalues obey $x^2=x$ so are zero or one. So the diagonal has zeros and ones on it. The number of ones is the rank of $P$ which is preserved under similarity transformations. Since we can see our matrix acts as identity on columns of $X$ (since $PX=X$) and annihates vectors in the orthogonal complement of the column space (since $X'$ times any such vector is zero), the rank of $P$ is $p$, the dimension of the column space of $X$.